# Keep a tcp connection open (boost-asio)

Tags: c++, networking, boost, tcp

I'm quite new to network programming and currently trying to implement a tcp-connection, using the boost.asio library, version 1.58 on Ubuntu 16.04.
So far I've worked through their tutorials from Daytime1 to Daytime3 (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) and everything works fine.

Now I am wondering, if there is a way to keep the tcp connection open after the socket's read_some(...)-method has been executed. If I execute the code as it is, the connection gets closed after the daytime is displayed once. How could I, as an example, manage to get the daytime every second without having to establish a new connection every second?
Thank you (: